# Xcode: "Message from debugger: unable to attach"

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, debugging

Every time I run my project (macOS Cocoa App) I get this message in the Xcode console:

> Message from debugger: unable to attach

I have already tried creating a new project (error still occurs), changing some „Signing settings“ (as mentioned in ["Message from debugger: unable to attach" when running Tests on OSX app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613223/message-from-debugger-unable-to-attach-when-running-tests-on-osx-app)) and reinstalling Xcode.

**Xcode Version:** Version 10.1 (10B61)
**OS: 10.13.6** (High Sierra)
**Model identifier:** iMac12,2

Comment: are you running project or unit tests and is it on device or simulator?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode could not launch app (unable to attach)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459488/xcode-could-not-launch-app-unable-to-attach)

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that I am programming a macOS Cocoa Application and I am trying to run it.

Comment: So I reinstalled Xcode and the Developer Tools once again. This time I was able to debug and compile my Cocoa App. But after the first time the error pops up again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. Also still using High Sierra. Every year, after the automatic renewal of the Mac Developer certificate, I have to 'trust' it in Keychain Access (look up new certificate, Get Info in the contextual menu, open Trust section, next to When using the certificate: Always Trust). Afterwards, I also did Clean Build Folder in Xcode, don't know if that was needed. But my debugger is now happy again.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34446026)